# Adding a property to a list c# that doesn't contain it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that returns a `List` of datatype `<Reserva>`. This class `Reserva` only has 4 **properties** which I can return with this method.

Within my diagram `Reserva` is a class that only is instanced within `<Espectaculo>`

I want to add a **property** to the new `List` I´m creating, for example I want to add the name of the `Espectaculo`: `e.name`

```
public List<Reserva> reservasNoPagas()
{
    List<Reserva> reservasNoPagas = new List<Reserva>();

    foreach (Espectaculo e in espectaculos)
    {
       reservasNoPagas.AddRange(e.reservasNoPagas());

       //somewhere here I want to add e.name to the reservasNoPagas
    }

    return reservasNoPagas;
}
```

Comment: do you understand your own question? I doubt that

Comment: I believe you've confused `Attribute` with property or field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add **properties** dynamically to classes. Inherit the class and add another in a new class:

```
public class ReservaExtended : Reserva
{
    public string ExtraProperty { get; set; }
}
```